# How to patch instruction with a call to a thunk function?

Tags: ghidra, patching, call

I started to use ghidra to begin doing some crackmes, and I need to change an instruction to a call to a thunk function. However, when I export the program back, I get a segfault.

Inspecting it with gdb, it looks like the jump address points an area with null bytes (there is one quite near the jump location)

```
segfault : 0x555556c700b8  add    BYTE PTR [rax],al
```

Also, as I was typing the new instruction in ghidra, it proposed me several opcodes, with no label to differentiate them, and for example, some of them would display another function afterward if I click on them (with the same function name, different namespace since the program was c++). Also, there was opcodes with 5 bytes, and other with 6...

How to know which one is the right one ?

Comment: That instruction isn't an intentional trap, that's just what null bytes disassemble to in x86.